# Parse database returns duplicate results?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to grab results from parse table by following query

```
NSInteger skip = self.objectsArray.count;

PFQuery *innerQuery = [PFUser query];
[innerQuery whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"HubObjects"];
[query whereKey:@"isActive" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
[query whereKey:@"Location" nearGeoPoint:self.location withinMiles:200];
[query whereKey:@"Hub" equalTo:self.hub];
[query whereKey:@"RTUser" doesNotMatchQuery:innerQuery];
[query orderByDescending:@"Points"];

query.skip = skip;
query.limit = 3;
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *HubObjects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        //do success stuff
    } else {
        //do error stuff
    }
}];
```

It says basically give me an array of objects within certain limits, important to note are query.limit, query.skip and orderByDescending

this returns as expected but with orderByDescending it gives me objects with "Lowest Points" where as it should be returning objects with highest points first also further results (pagination) gives duplicate results of the first time.

I tried using orderByAscending which gives correct behaviour (Lowest point objects first and on further pagination gives new objects with higher points), I also tried removing the limit constrain which gave the whole list of objects in correct order (highest to lowest Points)

the problem is How can i get results paginated (with limit) in order desired (highest to lowest) and without duplication?

Comment: Can you not just use `[query whereKey:@"RTUser" notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser]];` to simplify it (remove the inner query).

Comment: its a PFRelation field, I got it from documentation, besides this is not the problem

Comment: No worries, yeah, just looking at the problem now. Just thought I'd add it as a comment :)

Comment: Note, I didn't down vote.

Comment: Also, and I know this isn't the problem. But you should probably store `skip` as an `NSInteger` not an `NSNumber`. Also, what are your values of skip each time? Can you please log it each time?

Comment: thanks, my values for skip are 0,3,6,

Comment: I have nslog hubobjects returned and they are same every time, clarifying that it is not a tableview issue

Comment: Not sure why you said "but" it's a valid question and you didn't provide that information to begin with. Are you certain it is 0, 3, 6, etc... or is that what you're expecting it to be? You might be better off setting the skip value based on the number of objects you've already fetched (i.e. `skip = self.objects.count;` or something). Also, are you sure that the total number of users is not changing? If new users are added between calls then it could change the results of this causing duplicates.

Comment: No worries. Just trying to help. There's not much to go on as it depends a lot on calculated vars and also the data on the DB side. Can you show some actual output of some results to show what the problem is? The more info you provide the easier it is to see what (and possibly why it) is going wrong.

Comment: I tried skip the way you asked it still the same, the main thing which puzzles me is why results are not coming in order expected , why lowest first?

Comment: HubObjects fields of Interest are: location - pfgeopoint, isActive - bool, Hub - pfrelation,RTUser - pfrelation, Points - Number

Comment: Changing skip wouldn't fix it. It was just a suggestion. If you are using a variable only as an NSInteger (which you are) then store it as an NSInteger in the first place. How is `Points` defined on Parse?

Comment: as a Number see my comment above

Comment: OK, the only way I can think to find what's going on is to comment out all the constraints and test them one by one. AFAICT this should work. Comment out all but the `orderBy` and run it. Then add the constraints one by one again.

Comment: Also tried changing inner query to [pfuser currentUser] as suggested, no progress on problem

Comment: Did you change it to `notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser]`? Also, try removing the constraints. Get it so that it is simple enough so it does work. Then try adding the constraints back in one by one until it doesn't work again.

Comment: yes notEqualTo ,didnt work but useful tip, I did that already I tried with orderByAscending, works as expected but not desired, it seems somehow results are coming orderByAscending by default , also I tried removing limit which gave correct result in order desired but No pagination would be possible

Comment: Hmm... not sure now sorry. Nothing stands out as the cause of this and can't think what else I can ask without looking at the code lol.

Comment: Cool, thanks One more thing notEqualTo:[PFUser currentUser] you mentioned I was not sure will it work as this PFRelation can have many users added where as the Hub PfRelation field will only have 1 entry

Comment: Used your advice and tried querying by hiding all constraints and then adding one by one, it seems to me problem is with                            [query whereKey:@"Location" nearGeoPoint:self.location withinMiles:200];   PFGeoPoint, this one is causing order to mess up and giving duplicate results, please advice further coarse of action

Comment: Hmm... Thought that might be the case but couldn't find the docs. I think the nearGeoPoint queries override the sort order. I'm not sure you'll be able to fix it using an iOS query. You might have to create a cloud code function to do this instead.

Comment: Okey I think I got the problem...it says in the documentation in Geo Queries section "Note that if an additional orderByAscending:/orderByDescending: constraint is applied, it will take precedence over the distance ordering", some how this internal code of parse is messing up the results I am getting

Comment: I think I will fetch the result without location restraint and sort the array in code for geo locations manually

Comment: Please write this suggestion as the answer so that I can mark it as the default answer, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of investigating. :-)

It seems the geopoint search is overriding the sort order. I thought this might have been the case but I couldn't find the docs I read about it.

I don't think there will be a way around this using an iOS query.

You're best solution would probably be to write a cloud code function to return the information you need.

Otherwise remove the geopoint constraint and work it in after.

Thanks